# DIV Element with link not clickable on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, responsive-design

My div with ahref is not clickable on mobile device. I am not sure if it is covered by another div-element. However I've tried with z-index, position and so on for hours. I really need help on this one.

Link: www.truself.io
Browser: Firefox, as I use some Jquery at the moment to redirect to the Map view

[Mobile-View: Following element is not clickable on mobile only on desktop. Need this element to get clickable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fu2c.jpg)

Would be awesome if someone could help me. I am a very beginner :-)

Comment: i checked that link on mobile device it is working fine..but sometime `.job_filters` class covers the div (mostly image part but you can click the on the store name) which make it difficult to click.

Comment: @NitinWalia oh okay. Do you have an idea how to fix that? Cheers,

Comment: i won't be able to help unless you provide code..

Answer (score 0):

You can disable pointer-events in a parent element (probably transparent div) but have it still enabled for its child elements. For this all parenting divs get `pointer-events: none` and its clickable children get pointer-events reenabled by `pointer-events: auto`

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem recently: DIV element was not clickable on iOS devices with Safari or Chrome. The way to solve it was to attach an event to the DIV. See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click#Safari_Mobile

I'm not sure this is also your problem, but it might be helpful.

Comment: Hey thank you. I am very beginner. Do you have a sample code which I could add to main.js and modify to my div? Cheers